# How do I use my function from a.js in a button in b.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I’m trying to open an upload document dialogue when the user taps a button. I import the function to do this from another file (“upload-recording-button.js”) and try to use it in a button. However, I’ve gotten a number of errors such as “_uploadRecordingButton.uploadRecording is undefined.”

Based on other related Stack Overflow pages, I tried changing the button’s OnPress to this.uploadRecording, uploadRecording(this), this.uploadRecording(), and probably a few other variations. They all fail with variations of “function doesn’t exist.”

Here is part of the file with the function I’m calling:

upload-recording-button.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { DocumentPicker } from 'expo';

async function uploadRecording() {
  let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: '*/*'});

  if (!result.cancelled) {
    //upload function(result.uri);
  }
}

export default uploadRecording;
```

Main file

```
import { uploadRecording } from '../components/upload-recording-button';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    //header: null,
    title: 'Recents',
    // uploadRecording(this)
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={uploadRecording()}
        title="Add"
        color="#007AFF"
      />
    ),
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export function from `upload-recording-button.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { DocumentPicker } from 'expo';

export async function uploadRecording() {
  let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({type: '*/*'});

  if (!result.cancelled) {
    //upload function(result.uri);
  }
}
```

If there's only one function you're exporting from `upload-recording-button.js` you can use default export

```
export default function-name
```

and import it in the file where you want to use

```
import anyName from file-fath
```

Comment: And you need curly braces around the import for a non-default export, i.e. import { Something } from "somewhere";

Comment: Whoops, I already did that but forgot to add it to the cut-down version of the code I wrote above. See my edit.

Comment: @code-maniac I made those changes, and the function seems to have been successfully imported. However, now it seems to be running the second I launch the app instead of when the button is pressed. When I *do* press the button, I get “‘this.props.onPress(e)’, ‘this.props.onPress’ is an instance of Promise)”

Comment: @RyanTremblay you need to change this `onPress={uploadRecording()}` to this `onPress={()=>uploadRecording()}`